# Intersection Observer in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

**Can someone help me how can I do this in Reactjs?**

Can I iterate one IntersectionObserver for multiple child in reactjs

```js
const faders = document.querySelectorAll('.fade-in');

const appearOptions = {
    threshold: 1
};

const appearOnScroll = new IntersectionObserver( function(entries, appearOnScroll){
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if(!entry.isIntersecting){  
            return;
        }else{  
            entry.target.classList.add('appear')
            appearOnScroll.unobserve(entry.target)
        }
    })
}, appearOptions);

faders.forEach(fader =>{
    appearOnScroll.observe(fader)
})
```

Comment: Try using this library: https://react-hookz.github.io/web/?path=/docs/sensor-useintersectionobserver--example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### useIntersectionObserver.js

Use this custom hook. It creates an `IntersectionObserver` instance and saves it in a `useRef` hook. It tracks the elements that are being observed in a state. Whenever the state changes, it unobserves all elements and then reobserves the elements that remain in the state.

The advantages of creating a custom hook is that you can reuse the hook and implement it on multiple occasions.

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useIntersectionObserver = ({ root = null, rootMargin = '0px', threshold = 0 }) => {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([]);
  const [observedNodes, setObservedNodes] = useState([]);
  const observer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (observer.current) {
      observer.current.disconnect();
    }

    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(entries => setEntries(entries), {
      root,
      rootMargin,
      threshold
    });

    const { current: currentObserver } = observer;

    for (const node of observedNodes) {
      currentObserver.observe(node);
    }

    return () => currentObserver.disconnect();
  }, [observedNodes, root, rootMargin, threshold]);


  return [entries, setObservedNodes];
};

export default useIntersectionObserver;
```

#### app.js

Use the hook where you need to observe your elements. Create references to the elements that you need to observe and pass them to the hook after the first render.

The `entries` state will contain an array of [`IntersectionObserverEntry`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry) objects. Loop over it whenever the `entries` state changes and assert your logic, like adding a class.

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import useIntersectionObserver from './useIntersectionObserver';

function App() {
  const targets = useRef(new Set());

  const [entries, setObservedNodes] = useIntersectionObserver({
    threshold: 1
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setObservedNodes(() => ([...targets.current]));
  }, [setObservedNodes]);

  useEffect(() => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        entry.target.classList.add('appear');

        setObservedNodes(observedNodes => 
          observedNodes.filter(node => node !== entry.target)
        );
      }
    }
  }, [entries, setObservedNodes]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="fade-in" ref={element => targets.current.add(element)}></div>
      <div className="fade-in" ref={element => targets.current.add(element)}></div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. useRef is new to me so i'll do some digging.