# Add css class when element is in view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I have this pretty common use case. Apply a css class when the element is in view. I came across this code which is a great use but I'd like to apply a class to a specific element when it comes into view. Not when the scroll reaches a specific part of the screen. Hopefully with vanilla JS, any ideas. I'm thinking the `getElementById` needs to be used in some fashion, also would this also be possible only for mobile?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function ScrollEffect() {

   const [state, setstate] = useState(false);

  const changeClass = () => {
    const scrollValue = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    if(scrollValue > 200)
    {
      setstate(true);
    }
    else{
      setstate(false);
    }
      
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', changeClass);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 className={ state ? "blue" : "" }>Hello, World</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ScrollEffect;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Browser API made exactly for this use case, its called `IntersectionObserver`, it will trigger callback, when selected dom element is in view.

You can use some [libraries](https://github.com/thebuilder/react-intersection-observer), or you can implement it by yourself.

Great answer for creating custom hook is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908840/intersection-observer-in-reactjs)

[Api Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)